# Creating readStream for file in Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

Readstreams for firebase storage:

I have files in my Google firebase storage for which I want to create a read stream (using javascript/node js). (I then intend to pipe this read stream to some middleware and then a write stream, but this is unimportant for the question.) The code snippet shows what I'm doing, but when I print the readStream to console I get a DestroyableTransform object instead of a ReadableStream. I feel like my code is very similar to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/File#createReadStream). Does anyone know what might be wrong?

```
const filePath = 'image.png';
const getReadStream = (filePath) => {
    let file;
    try {
        file = admin
            .storage()
            .bucket()
            .file(filePath);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    const readStream = file.createReadStream()
        .on('error', (err) => {
            throw err;
        });
    console.log(readStream);
    return readStream;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a possible answer.

```
const filePath = 'image.png';
const getReadStream = (filePath) => {
    let file;
    try {
        file = admin
            .storage()
            .bucket(filePath);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    const readStream = file.createReadStream()
        .on('error', (err) => {
            throw err;
        });
    console.log(readStream);
    return readStream;
};
```

You should exclude the inner "file" sentence.

Comment: I was unable to get that working, although I did manage to do it by using the Bucket method .getFilesStream() and then filtering the results I needed. I may come back to trying to get his approach to work in the future. Thanks!